# Given numbers from 1 to 2^32-1, one is missing. How to find the missing number optimally?

Tags: algorithm

You are given 2^32-2 unique numbers that range from 1 to 2^32-1. It's impossible to fit all the numbers into memory (thus sorting is not an option). You are asked to find the missing number. What would be the best approach to this problem?

---

Let's assume you cannot use big-integers and are confined to 32bit ints.

`int`s are passed in through standard in.

Comment: How are you 'given' the list of numbers?

Comment: What does it mean -- impossible to fit everything into memory?

In other words -- how much memory (or 4 bytes words) do you have?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

*Major Edit:* Trust me to make things much harder than they have to be.

#### XOR all of them.

I'm assuming here that the numbers are 1 to 2<sup>32</sup> - 1 *inclusive*. This should use 1 extra memory location of 32 bits.

*EDIT:* I thought I could get away with magic. Ah well.

### Explanation:

For those who know how Hamming Codes work, it's the same idea.

Basically, for all numbers from 0 to 2<sup>n</sup> - 1, there are exactly 2<sup>(n - 1)</sup> 1s in each bit position of the number. Therefore xoring all those numbers should actually give 0. However, since one number is missing, that particular column will give one, because there's an odd number of ones in that bit position.

*Note:* Although I personally prefer the ** operator for exponentiation, I've changed mine to ^ because that's what the OP has used. Don't confuse ^ for xor.

Comment: Question says from 1 to 2^32-1, so xoring all numbers is enough as it's said above.

Comment: Thanks @Grzegorz, I made it far more complicated than it had to be.

Comment: You can use <sup></sup> instead of ^ to remove all ambiguity.

Answer (score 12):

Add all the numbers you are given up using your favourite big integer library, and subtract that total from the sum of all the numbers from 1 to 2^32-1 as obtained from the [sum of arithmetic progression formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_progression)

Comment: You don't even need a big integer library, `ulong` (an unsigned 64-bit integer) will do just fine.

Comment: You don't have to do either (64bits or arithmetic progression). Just count how many times each bit occurs, and you'll notice that sum==2^31 mod 2^32. Add all numbers, the missing one is 2^31-sum.

Comment: Are you sure? It's true that 0+1=1, but for all other n>1, xor-sum(0...2^n-1)=0, because exactly half the 2^n numbers have a 1 bit, and you can make matched pairs (2^(n-1)) of those 1-bits for n>1. Each pair when xored has a 0 bit in that position and thus so does the xor-sum of all the numbers.

Answer (score 4):

Use bitwise operator XOR. Here are example in JavaScript:

```
var numbers = [6, 2, 4, 5, 7, 1]; //2^3 exclude one, starting from 1
var result = 0;

//xor all values in numbers
for (var i = 0, l = numbers.length; i < l; i++) {
    result ^= numbers[i]; 
}

console.log(result); //3

numbers[0] = 3; //replace 6 with 3
//same as above in functional style
result = numbers.reduce(function (previousValue, currentValue, index, array) {return currentValue ^= previousValue;});

console.log(result); //6
```

The same in C#:

```
int[] numbers = {3, 2, 4, 5, 7, 1};

int missing = numbers.Aggregate((result, next) => result ^ next);

Console.WriteLine(missing);
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you can get the Size() you can use some binary approach. Select the set of numbers n where n< 2^32 -2 / 2. then get a count. The missing side should report a lower count. Do the process iteratively then you will get the answer

Answer (score 0):

If you do not have `XOR`, then of course you can do the same with ordinary "unchecked" sum, that is sum of 32-bit integers with "wrap around" (no "overflow checking", sometimes known as `unchecked` context).

This is addition modulo 2<sup>32</sup>. I will consider the "unsigned" case. If you 32-bit int uses two's complement, it is just the same. (To a mathematician, two's complement is still just addition (and multiplication) modulo 2<sup>32</sup>, we only pick a different canonical representative for each equivalence class modulo 2<sup>32</sup>.)

If we had had *all* the non-zero 32-bit integers, we would have:

```
1 + 2 + 3 + … + 4294967295 ≡ 2147483648
```

One way of realizing this is to take the first and the last term together, they give zero (modulo 2<sup>32</sup>). Then the second term (`2`) and the second-last term (`4294967294`) also give zero. Thus all terms cancel except the middle one (`2147483648`) which is then equal to the sum.

From this equality, imagine you subtract one of the numbers (call it `x`) on both sides of the `≡` symbol. From this, you see that you find the missing number by starting from `2147483648` and subtracting (still `unchecked`) from that all of the numbers you are given. Then you end up with the missing number:

```
missingNumber ≡ 2147483648 - x1 - x2 - x3 - … - x4294967294
```

Of course, this is the same as moonshadow's solution, just carried out in the ring of integers modulo 2<sup>32</sup>.

---

The elegant `XOR` solution (sykora's answer) can also be written in the same way, and with that `XOR` functions as both `+` and `-` at the same time. That is, if we had *all* the non-zero 32-bit integers, then

```
1 XOR 2 XOR 3 XOR … XOR 4294967295 ≡ 0
```

and then `XOR` with the missing number `x` on both sides of the `≡` symbol to see that:

```
missingNumber ≡ x1 XOR x2 XOR x3 XOR … XOR x4294967294
```