# Find the missing number in a  group {0......2^k -1} range

Tags: arrays, algorithm, numbers

Given an array that has the numbers `{0......2^k -1}` except for one number , 
find a good algorithm that finds the missing number.

Please notice , you can only use :

- for `A[i]` return the value of bit `j`.
- swap A[i] with A[j].

My answer : use divide & conquer , check the bit number K of all the numbers , if the K bit (now we're on the LSB) is `0` then move the number to the `left side`, if the `K` bit is `1` then move the number to the `right side`.
After the 1st iteration , we'd have two groups , where one of them is bigger than the other , so we continue to do the same thing, with the smaller group , and I think that I need to check the K-1 bit this time.

But from some reason I've tried with 8 numbers , from `0.....7` , and removed `4` (say that I want to find out that `4` is the missing number) , however to algorithm didn't work out so good. So where is my mistake ?

Comment: If you want a fix for your algorithm then you might want to make your algorithm more explicit. And indeed tell us what went wrong with your test of 0..7. At a glance it looks like it should work but without the implementation details its hard to tell where it went wrong. Of course if you have a low enough k that overflow isn't a problem then the summing answer is best. My reading of the question is that arithmatic isn't allowed but this seems like a fairly abirtrary restriction. Is it worth asking for the use case here?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Given numbers from 1 to 2^32-1, one is missing. How to find the missing number optimally?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/824373/given-numbers-from-1-to-232-1-one-is-missing-how-to-find-the-missing-number-o)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ron,

your solution is correct. This problem smells Quicksort, doesn't it ?

What you do with the Kth bit (all 0's to the left, 1's to the right) is a called a partition - you need to find the misplaced elements in pairs and swap them. It's the process used in Hoare's Selection and in Quicksort, with special element classification - no need to use a pivot element.

You forgot to tell in the problem statement how many elements there are in the array (2^k-2 or more), i.e. if repetitions are allowed.

If repetitions are not allowed, every partition will indeed be imbalanced by one element. The algorithm to use is an instance of Hoare's Selection (only partition the smallest halve). At every partition stage, the number of elements to be considered is halved, hence O(N) running time. This is optimal since every element needs to be known before the solution can be found.

[If repetitions are allowed, use modified Quicksort (recursively partition both halves) until you arrive at an empty half. The running time is probably O(N Lg(N)) then, but this needs to be checked.]

You say that the algorithm failed on your test case: you probably mis-implemented some detail.

An example:

Start with
5132670 (this is range {0..7})

After partitioning on bit weight=4 you get
0132|675

where the shortest half is
675 (this is range {4..7})

After partitioning on bit weight=2, you get
5|67

where the shortest half is
5 (this is range {4..5})

After partitioning on bit weight=1, you get
|5

where the shortest half is empty (this is range {4}).
Done.

Answer (score 5):

I assume you can build xor bit function using get bit j.

The answer will be (xor of all numbers)

**PROOF:** `a xor (2^k-1-a) = 2^k-1` (a and (2^k-1-a) will have different bits in first k positions).
Then `0 xor 1 xor ... xor 2^k-1 = (0 xor 2^k-1) xor (1 xor 2^k-2).... (2^(k-1) pairs) = 0`.
if number n is missing the result will be n, because `0 xor 1 xor 2....xor n-1 xor n+1 xor ... = 0 xor 1 xor 2....xor n-1 xor n+1 xor ... xor n xor n = 0 xor n = n`

**EDIT:** This will not work if k = 1.

Comment: This is a great answer but strictly by the question you'd need to be able to set bits to create an xor function which is not explicitly allowed. The maths is elegant enough though that you get a +1 from me anyway. Especially because you don't have to worry about overflows as you do for the sum solution. :)

Comment: Pedantic mode on: this is wrong for k = 1. Pedantic mode off: That's what I would have suggested too. +1

Answer (score 3):

for `n` just add them all and subtract the result from n*(n+1)/2
n*(n+1)/2 is sum of 1...n all numbers. If one of them is missing, then sum of those n-1 numbers will be n*(n+1)/2-`missingNumber`
Your answer is: n*(n+1)/2-`missingNumber` where `n` is 2^k-1

Comment: Of course, this answers the question, while ignoring the fact that as a homework problem such a solution is not allowed. +1 anyway :)

Comment: This is a great answer , but you're ignoring the instructions .Please notice , you can only use :

*for A[i] return the value of bit j.

*swap A[i] with A[j].  Thanks :)

Comment: are the given numbers in ascending order?

Comment: If yes i think I have a solution with complexity of `k` and without swaping

Answer (score 1):

Given the fact that for a given bit position `j`, there are exactly `2^(k-1)` numbers which have it set to 0, and `2^(k-1)` which have it set to 1 use the following algorithm.

```
 start with an array B of boolean of size k 
 init the array to false everywhere
 for each number A[i]
   for each position j 
    get the value v
    if v is 1 invert the boolean at position j
   end for
 end for
```

If a position is false at the end then the missing number does have a zero at
this position, otherwise it has a one (for `k >1`, If `k = 1` then it is the inverse). Now to implement your array of booleans
create a number of size `2k`, where the lower `k` are set to `0`, and the upper 
are set to `1`. Then

```
invert the boolean at position j
```

is simply *

```
 swap B[j] with B[j+k].
```

With this representation the missing number is the lower `k` elements of the array 
`B`. Well this algorithm is still `O(k*2^k)` but you can say it is `O(n*log(n))`
of the input.

Answer (score 1):

you can consider elements as string of k bits and at each step i if the number of ones or zeros in position i is 2^(k-i) you should remove all those strings an continue for example
100  111 010
101 110 000 011
so
100 111 101 110 all will be removed
and between 010 000 011 , 010 and 011 will be removed because their second bit is 1
000 remain and its rightmost bit is zero so 001 is the missing number