# Finding a missing number?

Tags: algorithm

I came across this very interesting question?
I have 300 million SSN numbers (9 digits number)

Find the SSN number which is missing?

You have unlimited drive space but just 2MB of RAM?

Comment: WHy -1?? I thought I posted in algorithm section. I am aware of stackoverflow policies but I wonder what sort of question you expect in "algorithm" section?

Comment: Can be a possible duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/824373/given-numbers-from-1-to-232-1-one-is-missing-how-to-find-the-missing-number-o

Comment: What do you mean THE missing number? There will be 600,000,000 missing numbers since the 9 digit numbers are 900 million.

Comment: I would expect an interesting question *with sufficient details* along with some "thoughts" on how to solve it or "implementation ideas" to show effort ..

Comment: @izomorphius, not all SSNs are available for general use. Areas 000, 666 and 9xx are non-assignable. In addition, only about half a billion have been issued since the 30s. Having said that, there's still a couple hundred thousand "missing" from OP's list.

Comment: @paxdiablo I do not see how this helps to answer my question. Even if you are right the missing number is not one but more like several hundred million.

Comment: Voting to close this. I feel this can be marked as a duplicate.

Comment: @izomorphius, it doesn't answer your question, I actually _agree_ with you. I was just correcting your assumption that there were 600 million more SSNs. Your question is still a valid one even though the shortfall is "only" 200 million or so.

Comment: From the FAQ: "You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face." - this seems to me to be an "invented" problem, especially given the constraints. Won't vote to close but this is borderline at best.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's look at this by first analyzing a smaller problem. Say you have 9 unique 1 digit numbers and you are trying to find the one missing. What you can do is add up the 10 unique 1 digit numbers:

0 + 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + 6 + 7 + 8 + 9 = 45

Then you can add up the 9 numbers you have and subtract the difference to find the one that is missing. The same strategy can be applied to your question but the problem becomes finding the sum as you don't want to do that by hand if possible.

Let's look at the case of 100 unique 2 digit numbers:

The first 10 numbers = 45 (as shown above)

The next 10 numbers will all have an additional 10 + 1 digit number value, giving us a result of 145. The next 10, each have an additional 20 -> 245, and so on until we get to the last 10 numbers having the sum of 945. We add these all together and get 4950.

Now, let's look for a pattern that is related to the amount of digits.

1 digit = 45 (not much going on there but it does give an additional data point to verify)

2 digits = 4950

Let's think back to how we were adding the numbers, probably easier to look at 2 digit case first.

Let's call x the number in 1 through 9 we were at for the leftmost digit. We would add the answer for the previous number of digits to 10 * (x -> with 1 zero afterwards, in case of the 2 digit solution.) So here we could again take advantage of the answer we found with 1 digit and see that 10 * 10 + 20 * 10 + 30 * 10 + 40 * 10 + 50 * 10 + 60 * 10 + 70 * 10 + 80 * 10 + 90 * 10 = 10 * (10 + 20 + 30 + 40 + 50 + 60 + 70 + 80 + 90) = 100 * (1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9) = 100 * 45 = 4500. Then we also have 45 ten times in there as well so that gets us 450. 4500 + 450 = 4950.

Now, its time to generalize into a recursive equation.

Sum for all n-digit unique numbers =

1(with n zeros after) * ans(n-1) + 1(with n-1 zeros) * ans(n-1) + 1(with n-2 zeros) * ans(n-2) ... 10 * 45 + 1 * 0

I'm done factoring it any further but I hope I made it clear and that this answers your question with some mathematical fun as well!

Answer (score 3):

Assuming only one element is missing ..
Since we have memory constraints we need to partially load file into memory so  divide given file 3*10pow(8)/2MB and apply below method to part of file(technique borrowed from external sort). 
The technique is simple XOR all the elements. Basic concept is from hamming codes. If we XOR all elements from 1 to 2power(n-1) the result should be equal to zero . If an element is missing the result will be missing number.

In hectic method :
We can also apply arithmetic sum of natural number from 1 to n that is n(n+1)/2 and then in one traversal calculate sum of given array and find the difference between n(n+1)/2 and obtained sum .It should give missing number . As sum of billion number is a very big number to handle.